# Installed VS 2012 and now I'm getting "Validation of ViewState Mac failed" exception on the login page of my project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

The login page includes one login control and little code in the codebehind - it uses a custom membership provider however.

I opened it in VS2012 initially, and it performed an update of the project without asking (it made a backup and apparently the files are backward compatible with 2010, so that's not too bad) but I now get this error whenever I use the log in page - even after rolling back to my original code from SVN and going back to 2010.

I can only assume there was an update to IIS or my .net version during the install that changed something, but I don't know what it would be and there is very little information on google. This error can have a number of causes.

Has anyone else had this issue? Does anyone know what might have caused it?

If I use the "EnableViewStateMac" set to false it does not solve the problem - if I also set enableEventValidation to "false" it DOES fix this issue, but I don't want to disable event validation randomly if I don't know what the error is or what's causing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: That fixed it.. thank-you. I hope this helps someone else at least!